# GLPSOL Problem within the Operation Research field

Tags: glpk

For a couple of months now, I am trying to solve an operational research model with glpk on a mac. The thing is that I have searched throughout the internet and also I have tried to find help in universities based in Athens Greece but it seems that noone has a clue regarding the specific program. So, my MODEL is the following:

```
#PARAMETERS
#

param P;
param D;
param S;
param R;
param B;
param LS;
param CLNGs;
param Tp;
param H;
param Frest;
param MA;
param f;
param Cvr {1..B};
param Cvf {1..B};
param Vv {1..B};
param Qv {1..B};
param Demand {1..R};
param d {1..P, 1..D};


# VARIABLES
#

var z{1..B}  >=0, integer;
var x{1..P,1..R,1..B,1..S,1..D} >=0, continuous;
var y{1..P,1..B,1..R,1..S,1..D} >=0, integer;

# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
#

minimize F {p<>m}: sum {p in 1..P} sum {m in 1..D} 
sum {v in 1..B}Cf[v]*d[p,m]*y[p,m,v] + H* sum {v in 1..B} Cr[v]*z[v] + 
sum {s in 1..S} sum {r in 1..R} sum {v in 1..B} CLNG[s]*Q[v]*x[s,r,v];

# CONSTRAINTS
#

s.t. constr1 {r in 1..R, r<>p, r<>m }: sum {p in 1..P} 
sum {v in 1..B}Q[v]*x[p,r,v] - sum{m in 1..D} 
sum{v in 1..B}Q[v]*x[r,m,v] >=Demand[r];

s.t. constr2 {p in 1..P, r in 1..R, v in 1..B}: y[p,r,v] >= x[p,r,v];

s.t. constr3 { r in 1..R, v in 1..B}: 
sum {p in 1..P} x[p,r,v] >= sum {m in 1..D} x[r,m,v];

s.t. constr4 { p in 1..P, v in 1..B, p<>m}: 
sum {m in 1..D} y[m,p,v] = sum {m in 1..D} y[p,m,v];

s.t. constr5 {v in 1..B, p<>m}: H*z[v] >= 1/V[v] *sum{p in 1..P} 
sum{m in 1..D} d[p,m]*y[p,m,v] + 
sum{p in 1..P}*(T[p]*sum{m in 1..D}y[p,m,v]);

s.t. constr6 {p in 1..P, r in 1..R, v in 1..B}: 
Q[v]*y[p,r,v] <= Frest*y[p,r,v];

s.t. constr7 {v in 1..LS, i<>j}: sum {i in 1..R} 
sum {j in 1..R} x[i,j,v] = 0;

s.t. constr8 {s in 1..S}: sum {r in 1..R} 
sum {v in 1..V} Q[v]*x[s,r,v] <= MA[s];

s.t. constr9 {s in 1..S, r in 1..R}: x[s,r,v] >= f*y[s,r,v];

end;
```

And my DATA:

```
#test comments

param P := 7;
param D := 7;
param S := 3;
param R := 4;
param B := 4;
param LS := 2;
param CLNGs := 200;
param Tp := 24;
param H := 30;
param Frest := 1000000000
param MA := 10000000000
param f :=0.8
param Cvr : 1 :=
1 510000
2 600000
3 700000
4 900000
;

param Cvf : 1 :=
1 22
2 26
3 32
4 42
;

param Vv : 1 :=
1 24
2 26
3 28 
4 30
;

param Qv : 1 :=
1 5000
2 7500
3 10000
4 15000
;

param Demand : 1 :=
1 2595.9
2 3781.2
3 1668
4 372.9
;

param d: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7:=
1 0 1663 996 306 291 333 372
2 1663 0 2413 1867 1905 1856 2050
3 996 2413 0 924 938 761 1103
4 306 1867 924 0 107 202 110
5 291 1905 938 107 0 122 184
6 333 1856 761 202 122 0 302
7 372 1050 1103 110 184 302 0
;

end;
```

When I am trying to run this i get always the following error:

```
thesis.mod:29: syntax error in variable statement
Context: ..... P , 1 .. R , 1 .. B , 1 .. S , 1 .. D } >= 0 ,continuous
MathProg model processing error
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'continuous' attribute defined in the var statement of the GMPL language. Variables are by default continuous.

Please, read doc/gmpl.pdf that comes with GLPK.